# Using Click event and Dragend event

Tags: javascript, events, bing-maps

I am wanting to have to event on my pins. one that when the user clicks on a pin a click method is called. A second method would be dragend for when the user drags the pin.

I currently have the following event handlers:

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', displayInfobox);
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, "dragend", endDragHandler);
```

the problem is that when the user only clicks on the pin, the endDragHandler gets called first and then calls the click method.

Any Suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up comming up with was to check the current location and see if it was still in the same spot.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly seems strange that `dragend` fires before `click`, but you are right this is indeed the case. The easiest workaround I can think of is this: rather than subscribing to the `click` event, suscribe to the `mousedown` event instead:

```
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'mousedown', displayInfobox);
Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, "dragend", endDragHandler);
```

`mousedown` will fire before `dragend`. So if you can get away with using 'mousedown', I would suggest that you do this.  If you must use `click`, things might get complicated.

Comment: I actually tried mousedown aswell. It didnt work either as it had the same results.

Comment: @Johnston That's strange then.  When I tried it in v7 of the bing maps javascript api, mousedown gets called before dragend.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question has already been answered, I found a solution at [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1173178/How-to-Detect-in-Bing-Map-Version-It-Is-Click-Even) CodeProject link, similar to what @johnston suggested above:

Basically on click event of pushpin, the new and old latitude/longitude is being compared in 3 decimal values. If it matches its assumed its a click event, otherwise its a drag event. 
I am though amazed as to why Bing team hasn't looked itself into this weird issue, that took me hours to sort out. Bing API should itself address this issue.